# Move tkinter canvas windows below other widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tk.Canvas's `.create_window` to place buttons on my canvas, to allow a 'scrolling' effect, where I can cycle through a list of buttons:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpgQy.gif)

As seen in the gif, there is a scrollbar on the right which allows scrolling vertically of the canvas, and the canvas created windows of buttons can be cycled through. However, as seen, the buttons overlap the scrollbar. Is it possible for the windows to be set to appear only within the canvas widget? Changing the master of the button does not have an effect:

```
button = tk.Button(self, image=self.data[i].image, anchor='nw', width=400, height=72, highlightthickness=0, bd=0, relief='flat', bg='#dfdbda', compound='left', text="thing", fg='black', font='System, 10')
buttonwindow = self.canvas.create_window(5, 10, anchor='nw', window=button)
```

No matter which configuration options are given, the window still seems to pop out of the canvas widget. Why does it do this? Is there a better alternative to create_window, where I can put buttons in a canvas widget?

Comment: The problem does not seem to be the buttons but the scrollbar. You put the scrollbar within the canvas, which leads to it being overwritten by canvas objects. Just create it as widget beside the canvas (plus one column, if you use grid) and it will not be overlapped anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found (the scrollbar was never inside the canvas):
I put the set the master of the buttons to the canvas, which restricted them purely to that widget.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: don't put the scrollbar inside the canvas. Use the same master for the scrollbar as you do for the canvas. Also, the buttons need to be a child of the canvas.

Since you didn't provide enough code to create a working example, here's a contrived example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class ButtonScroller(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="lightgray", bd=2, relief="groove")
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.buttons = []
        self.data = []

    @property
    def count(self):
        return len(self.buttons)

    def add_button(self, image, text):
        bbox = self.canvas.bbox("all") or (0,0,0,0)
        x, y = 4, bbox[3]+5

        # use a fake image to keep the example simple...
        self.data.append(image)
        button = tk.Button(self.canvas, image=image, anchor='nw', width=400, height=72,
                           highlightthickness=0, bd=0, relief='flat', bg='#dfdbda',
                           compound='left', text=text, fg='black', font='System, 10')
        self.buttons.append(button)
        self.canvas.create_window(x, y, anchor="nw", window=button)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

def add_button():
    # create a dummy image to simplify this example
    image = tk.PhotoImage(width=64, height=64)
    n = buttonframe.count + 1
    text = f"Button #{n}"
    buttonframe.add_button(image, text)

root = tk.Tk()
buttonframe = ButtonScroller(root, bd=1, relief="raised")
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

add_button = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Add", command=add_button)
add_button.pack(side="left", padx=2, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The scrollbar is not inside the canvas, they are both put in the same frame.

Comment: @xerp152: the other problem is that the buttons need to be a child of the canvas, which is part of this answer.